# Reshaping Tensor in C

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, c-api

How can I reshape TF_Tensor* using Tensorflow's C_api as it's being done in C++?

```
TensorShape inputShape({1,1,80,80});

Tensor inputTensor;
Tensor newTensor;

bool result = inputTensor->CopyFrom(newTensor, inputShape);
```

I don't see a similar method using the tensorflow's c_api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow C API operates with a `(data,dims)` model - treating data as a flat raw array supplied with the needed dimensions.

**Step 1**: Allocating a `new` Tensor

Have a look at `TF_AllocateTensor`([ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L248)):

```
TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern TF_Tensor* TF_AllocateTensor(TF_DataType,
                                                   const int64_t* dims,
                                                   int num_dims, size_t len);
```

Here:

1. `TF_DataType`: The `TF` equivalent of the data type you need from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L99).
2. `dims`: Array corresponding to dimensions of tensor to be allocated eg. `{1, 1, 80, 80}`
3. `num_dims`: length of dims(`4` above)
4. `len`: reduce(dims, *): i.e. 1*1*80*80*sizeof(DataType) = 6400*sizeof(DataType).

**Step 2**: Copying data

```
// Get the tensor buffer
auto buff = (DataType *)TF_TensorData(output_of_tf_allocate);
// std::memcpy() ...
```

[Here](https://github.com/saatviks/peloton/blob/master/src/brain/util/tf_session_entity/tf_session_entity_input.cpp#L45) is some sample code from a project I did a while back on writing a very light Tensorflow C-API Wrapper.

So, essentially your reshape will involve allocating your new tensor and copying the data from the original tensor into `buff`.

The Tensorflow C API isnt meant for regular usage and thus is harder to learn + lacking documentation. I figured a lot of this out with experimentation. Any suggestions from the more experienced developers out there?